# TFS2010 web access give 401

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access

I have a TFS2010 server that was moved from a workgroup to a domain. Version control and build are working fine (we do not have reporting or Sharepoint setup for that server). I can connect using the TFS admin console on the server using the `Tfs_admin` domain account and I can connect using VS2010 from my desk (domain account).

If I try to connect to Web access (`http://tfs.myDomain.com:8080/tfs/web`) I get a `401.2` error followed by a `401.1` in the IIS logs (`c:\inetpub\logs\Logfiles\W3SVC8080`). The IIS app pool is set to run in classic mode on V4.0 and using the `myDomain\Tfs_admin` account. If this is an authentication issue, what account should I use? I did try to use `myDomain\Tfs_admin` and even that does not work.

If I go to: `http://tfs.myDomain.com:8080/tfs/web/IndexLimited.aspx` I get a page but in Firebug I can see that all .css .js and images return a 404 not found. If I look in that directory on the server I can see the content.

I tried to log a ticket on the MSDN forums but I could still not get this resolved. Web access should not be so hard to setup?

Ok, more data: If I use the URL:tfs.myDomain.com:8080/tfs/Web in chrome I get challenged for username\password and I use myDomain\myAccount with the password(that works fine in VS2010) I then get the Ooops page and go to the IIS log file and I can see the "401.2 - Logon failed due to server configuration". On the next line in the log I see myDomain\myAccount and a "404.4 - No handler configured" next to it.

Comment: How is the authentication in your web.config?

Comment: FYI - (minor nitpick) There is nothing called "source safe" in TFS.  There is "source control" which is an altogether radically different thing than the product previously known as "Source Safe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate answering my own question but I got it working, not via an answer but by keeping at it till it is done. I tracked it down to static(images, css, js) content that is not delivered. I focused on one image:http://tfs.myDomain:8080/tfs/web/Resources/images/company_logo.gif and that was giving me:404.4 - No handler configured so I removed the StaticFile Handler Mapping(IIS>Sites>Team Foundation Server) and rebooted the machine. I added it back in IIS and everything started working.

Comment: Glad to see you got this resolved.  Interesting solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by reviewing this document:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883.aspx

There are a number of steps that you have to follow in order to change the environment that TFS is functioning in.

Comment: I did follow the docs, thanks. It was because everything else worked and not Web access that I made the post.